# Unable to Re-compile De-compiled Code

Tags: c#, ilspy

When I open [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) in ILSpy and try to navigate to 'this.Provider.Context.Db' in the MappedDataReader Constructor it doesn't work.

I also have the same problem if I de-compile it and try to re-compile it in VS.  VS says 'CS1061 'type' does not contain a definition for 'member' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).'

[Code Snippet of MappedDataReader Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peRYL.png)

How is .Net able to execute this assembly?

Comment: The project is open source, you can get the original source code for that class [right here](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#dev/Src/EntityFramework.BulkInsert/Helpers/MappedDataReader.cs) why are you using a decompiler at all?

Answer (score 1):

Decompiled source is unlikely to be the same as the original source.  The original source code was compiled into [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and the decompiler attempts to create functionally equivalent code from the IL with varying degrees of success.  It is not unlike the process of taking a chunk of english text, tranlating it to another language and translating it back, ala [Google Translate Sings](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjv7ori6P_OAhXKPj4KHWsFBVkQyCkIIDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D2bVAoVlFYf0&usg=AFQjCNEkEBUqHQs72MDYmz-UV5o7pLz4hg&sig2=tCKdGUjwU2qEfKUUAZEMLg).